# Python Interface to Website API with Basic Auth

Tags: python, python-requests, http-authentication

I have an [Python interface to the TVMaze website's API](https://github.com/srob650/pytvmaze) and they are implementing new features that will require basic HTTP auth.  All of the existing features will **not** require auth, so I don't want to change how users interact with those functions.

Should I simply make a new object that stores the username and api key and use methods of that object for the new features/functions that require authentication?  Something like:

```
class TVMazePremium(object):
    def __init__(self, username, api_key):
        self.username = username
        self.api_key = api_key

    def put(url):
        r = requests.put(url, auth=(self.username, self.api_key))

    def new_premium_function():
        self.put('www.foo.bar')

    def another_premium_function():
        self.put('www.foo.baz')
```

Then they could do:

```
premium = pytvmaze.TVMazePremium(myuser, myapikey)
premium.new_premium_function()
```

Is this a good way?  Is there something better?

Comment: One other option is to add the api_key as optional to your original class. This way, existing code can continue to work. You will want to add something to "set" the "api_key", not have it only in the constructor. Subclassing TVMazePremium from your original class might also be an option if you want to keep separate classes for "standard" and "premium".

Comment: There is no parent class to the other functions in my original code, so this would be a change in how the current code functions which I'd like to avoid.  Is it weird to have a bunch of functions that people can just call via `pytvmaze.some_func()` and then others where they need to set up this new premium class first?

Comment: That's hard to say. You are entitled to update the library the way it makes more sense for you: deprecation paths are not unheard of. If I were you, I would start a new class that covers both "standard" and "premium" and keep the old library around but as "deprecated" with a big notice that new users should use the new class, and old users should plan on migrating. At some point, you'll stop providing fixes to the old library. And later, you can pull it completely.

Comment: I actually like that idea a lot, thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad to be helpful. And thank you for your library. I haven't looked at it, but now I am curious to actually go and use it :-) Good luck!

Comment: New version of pytvmaze is live with the new class and premium API access.  Thanks again!